# PL SQL trigger doesn't work

Tags: sql, plsql

I have written a Trigger which fires on the insert or update of the table bestellung and I want it to change certain things when inserting or updating a file in the table. What I want to change I think you can see from the code.

I am working with APEX right now and when I try to insert an Order he always throws me the Error the Table is right now being changed and that the trigger maybe doesn't see the changes.

```
create or replace trigger bestellschluss_iuar
after insert or update on bestellung
for each row
DECLARE 
v_date2 DATE;
v_hour number;

BEGIN

select bestelldatum + 2 into v_date2 from bestellung where bestellid = :new.bestellid;
select EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TO_TIMESTAMP(SYSDATE))into v_hour FROM DUAL;       

IF :NEW.zieldatum IS NULL THEN
    IF v_hour > 17 THEN
        UPDATE bestellung
        SET zieldatum = bestelldatum + 3
        WHERE bestellid = :NEW.bestellid;
    ELSE
        UPDATE bestellung -- bestellung means order
        SET zieldatum = bestelldatum + 2 --and this means deliverydate = orderdate +2
        WHERE bestellid = :NEW.bestellid;
    END IF;
ELSIF v_date2 > :NEW.zieldatum THEN
        raise_application_error(-22501, 'Bestellungen für dieses Datum nicht möglich da zu Kurze Lieferzeit');
ELSIF (v_date2 = :NEW.zieldatum) AND v_hour > 18 THEN
        raise_application_error(-22502, 'Bestellungen um diese Uhrzeit für diesen Tag nicht mehr möglich');
END IF;
END;​
/
```

Comment: i think it should be before insert on second  line instead of after insert.

Comment: hmm now he always tells me that he doesnt find any data and error when running the trigger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger instead of an `AFTER` trigger here.  In a `BEFORE` trigger, you can access and change the values of the affected row before they get inserted or updated, by assigning to `:NEW.columnname`.  This is sufficient for you, as you are only querying/updating data in the row that the trigger has fired for.

This also avoids the 'table XYZ is mutating; trigger/function may not see it' error, because we are no longer attempting to query or update the table during a trigger that updates it.

I've had a go at rewriting your trigger as a `BEFORE` trigger.  Please note that I haven't tested that it works, other than creating a suitable table and verifying that the trigger compiles:

```
create or replace trigger bestellschluss_iubr
  before insert or update on bestellung
  for each row
DECLARE 
  v_date2 DATE;
  v_hour number;

BEGIN
  v_date2 := :NEW.bestelldatum + 2;
  v_hour := EXTRACT(HOUR FROM SYSTIMESTAMP);

  IF :NEW.zieldatum IS NULL THEN
    IF v_hour > 17 THEN
      :NEW.zieldatum := :NEW.bestelldatum + 3;
    ELSE
      :NEW.zieldatum := :NEW.bestelldatum + 2;
    END IF;
  ELSIF v_date2 > :NEW.zieldatum THEN
    raise_application_error(-22501, 'Bestellungen für dieses Datum nicht möglich da zu Kurze Lieferzeit');
  ELSIF (v_date2 = :NEW.zieldatum) AND v_hour > 18 THEN
    raise_application_error(-22502, 'Bestellungen um diese Uhrzeit für diesen Tag nicht mehr möglich');
  END IF;
END;
/
```